# AssertionError while using gulp. 'Task function must be specified'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bash, gulp

I'm trying to use Gulp as part of a React tutorial I'm walking through. After installing the dependencies I've been given;

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

This is the gulpfile.js which I am using

```js
'use strict';

// dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var renamed = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

// - SCSS/CSS

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

// Compile SCSS

gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){
    
    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
    

});

// detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);
});

// Run tasks
gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

And this outputs the following messages

generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='

The tutorial I am using was made in April 2017. Could it be something to do with conflicting versions?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look up how to migrate from gulp v3 to v4.  Yes, that code has v3 syntax in it which will not work in v4.

Comment: Hi thank you for this. I upgraded from v3 to v4 and it works fine. Will post what i've done below

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using v3 gulp, the problem was solved by upgrading to v4.

The code is below.

```js
'use strict';

// dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var renamed = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

// - SCSS/CSS

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

function compile_scss (done) {
    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(renamed({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
    done();
}

// detect changes in SCSS
function detect_change_scss (done) {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC)
    done();
}

// Run tasks
gulp.task("compile_scss", gulp.series(compile_scss, detect_change_scss, ));
```